# What do I define the coordinate system of this data set to?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I have an excel spreadsheet with lat and lon columns, and 5 additional columns with associated data. I want to open the data points in ArcMap 10.2. I was told that the data was:

based on a Lambert conformal projection with the following specifications:

Central latitude/longitude 40N, 97W

First secant angle  33N
Second secant angle 45N

Origin at -1872000.0, 828000.0 from center.

How do I open this data in Arcmap with the correct spatial reference system?

Comment: You say lat and lon columns. Are there lat/lon values in those columns or are they projected using the ProjCRS defn? What's the GeoCRS aka datum? NAD83?

Comment: If you have latitude and longitude, then points generated are NOT in Lambert.  If you can define what they *are* then getting to what you want them to be is easy. Just remember that latitude is Y (if you think "lon and lat", it helps keep things straight).

Answer (score 1):

After making some assumptions, here's a possible prj file for the definition that you gave. The assumptions are:

1. GeoCRS is NAD 1983
2. False easting is 1872000.0 meters (assuming the origin values are given in meters)
3. False northing is -828000.0 meters (this is the one that I feel most unsure about)

(2) and (3) are based on the statement that the 0,0 coordinates are -1872000, 828000. That means the center point of the projection has the opposite sign values. That is, +1872000.0, -828000.0.

PROJCS["USA_LCC",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1872000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-828000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-97.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",33.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",40.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Copy out the PROJCS[...]] string and put it into a text file **as a single line** with a carriage return at the end. Change file's extension to .prj. You can now use the import option to assign it to the data or the data frame.